# How do i configure vscode live preview for simple wordpress style.css edits?

Tags: css

I'm editing CSS on a very basic wordpress site on a remote server, using vscode. I'm interested in linking vscode to my browser window and having the site reload every time I save changes to style.css.

I've successfully installed the Live Preview vscode extension, and can see any saved changes to style.css when I manually refresh my browser, but browser isn't auto reloading on style.css save. What have I missed?